# When I run the roslaunch command, an RLException error occurs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ros, launch, gazebo-simu

The text is the same as the title.
I tried various methods on google to solve this error. But it doesn't work, so I need your help.
Anyone is welcome, please help me to solve this error.

```
awesometech@awesometech:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch urs_wearable world.launch

... logging to /home/awesometech/.ros/log/165b93fc-9d30-11ed-967c-a99cf3fa13f4/roslaunch-awesometech-4851.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

RLException: while processing /home/awesometech/catkin_ws/src/URSSimEnvironments/urs_wearable/launch/world.launch:
while processing /home/awesometech/catkin_ws/src/URSSimEnvironments/urs_wearable/launch/world.launch:
..
Invalid tag: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.

Arg xml is
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

this is my code I think there is no error in this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
<include file="$(find urs_wearable)/launch/world.launch">
<arg name="world" value="$(find urs_wearable)/worlds/test.world" />
<arg name="reference_latitude" value="32.319939" />
<arg name="reference_longitude" value="-106.763657" />
</include>
</launch>
```

Comment: is that something you wrote in Python script? I don't want to state the obvious, but... It seems that a recursive function never gets an ending point. Try to dig into which one it is.

Comment: The file extension is .xml. I'm currently working on Ubuntu and I want to find the endpoint of a recursive function, but I'm frustrated because I can't figure out which part is wrong.

Comment: what is inside the `world.launch`?

Comment: You need to include what is in your world launch file. You have a recursive dependency with your includes. Ex: A includes B and B includes A.

Comment: The code at the bottom is the world.launch file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what to try?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you’re launch file includes itself. This creates a circular dependency as it will never stop trying to include itself. Remove the following line:

```
<include file="$(find urs_wearable)/launch/world.launch">
```